# How to debug web php project step by step using eclipse luna

Tags: php, xdebug, zend-studio, eclipse-luna

I need to Debug line by line in my php project. I'm Trying many ways like xdebug/Zend etc. I'm using Eclipse Luna Php IDE.

Could anyone please guide me? I've wasted the last 2days without success.

Comment: Have you checked - https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug

Comment: yeah...Im already Follow These steps but While im Debugging the Script cant be retrieve into coding part...Project running asusual in debugging window...i need to stop the code in my breakpoint

Comment: One of the problems I've had is to make sure that the source path matches the path on the (I assume) remote system.  If you can include the settings you've got in Eclipse, this may help.

Comment: Where these configurations are present??

Comment: Probably from https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug#Debugging_using_the_default_DocumentRoot_.28http:.2F.2Flocalhost.29

Comment: improved language.

Comment: @Assafs what??????////

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHPStorm as IDE better than eclipse IDE.

Comment: Sorry For Asking...Can you please send me the link of php storm